# How to invoke a javascript function when the value of struts2 autocompleter changes

Tags: struts2, struts, autocomplete

I am using a struts2 autocompleter tag. Now i want to invoke a javascript function when user selects some value in the drop down. I tried onChange, onSelect, onClick event but nothing works :( Please tell me your suggestions on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd use Dojo "topics".

When a selection is made the `valueNotifyTopics` are fired. See the [autocompleter docs for details](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/autocompleter.html). There is an example there, shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.event.topic.subscribe("/value", function(value, key, text, widget){
    alert('inside a topic event. after value changed');
    //value : selected value (like "Florida" in example above)
    //key: selected key (like "FL" in example above)
    //text: text typed into textbox
    //widget: widget that published the topic
});
</script>   

<sx:autocompleter valueNotifyTopics="/value" href="%{#ajaxTest}" />
```

Note that the Dojo tags have been deprecated since Struts 2.1 and will be archived in the next release.

Comment: Thanks, i wondering if there is any way of doing it using normal struts2 autocompleter tag. Also in the given post what value should be given to href attribute?

Comment: @RachitAgrawal That is the normal S2 autocompleter tag. If you're using a different one, you should specify which one--are you referring to the jQuery plugin? The `href` attribute should be the URL returning possible completions.